# Setting a text = a string crashes my program

Tags: nsstring, label

I am new at this so be gentle.
I have this function:

```
- (void) Morepoint {
    gscore ++;
    scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gscore];
    lblscore.text = scoreString;
}
```

Where `gscore` is a global. `scoreString` is a NSString and `lblscore` is a label.
Every time I insert the function in my gameloop, the program stops to run.
Can anyone figure that out?
If I call the function from outside my gameloop, everything works fine, why?

Comment: What type is `gscore`?

Comment: gscore is an integer.

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with your code, so you need to provide a stacktrace.

Comment: A stacktrace?? i will have to read about that :-) But i will be back with a stacktrace.

Comment: I can figure out how to set a breakpoint but how do i provide you of the data?

Comment: You can use `bt` in the debugger console.

Comment: Ok :-) i got the bt to work. But i can't post the output here. Its too long. Can i send you a PM? and if so - whats your mail?

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the stacktrace there.

Answer (score 0):

You own the object returned from `initWithFormat` which you are responsible for releasing, but you don't own the object returned from `stringWithFormat` which returns an autoreleased string and so do not need to release it (if you do want to have ownership of it, you must retain it).

So for resolving your issue try to assign your value like this,

```
- (void) Morepoint 
{
    gscore ++;
    scoreString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",gscore];
    lblscore.text = scoreString;      

}
```

Hope this helps you. Just Give it a try :)

Comment: unfurtunatly it does'nt work :-( i get this messages : release is unavailable : not available in automatic refenrence counting mode. ARC forbids explicit message sent of release ???

Comment: In case of ARC Enabled, just do not release it. See updated code